# Virtualbox Resolution mismatch

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, debian

I use and up-to-date Windows 10 guest on a up-to-date Stretch Debian host.

All was ok until last system upgrade. Virtualbox was upgraded from 5.1.4 to 5.1.6, as well as other packages. I upgraded guest tools.

Now, display is awful in the guest. Fonts are barely readable.

The issue seems to come from a resolution mismatch. In full screen, W10 reports 1829x1029, whereas my host is 2560x1440.

There is not scale factor, neither in Virtualbox nor in Windows.

Tested:

- Downgrade Virtualbox to 5.1.4
- Reinstall of guest tools
- VBoxManage setextradata Windows CustomVideoMode1 2560x1440x32
- VBoxManage controlvm Windows setvideomodehint 2560 1440 32

I also have some glitches on mouse interactions, but it may be linked with the resolution issue.

I would appreciate any hint.

[Edit 20160923: video memory is 256 MB]

[Edit 20160924: on a second screen, natively 1920x1200, the guest correctly reports a 1920x1200 resolution. The issue may comes from high dpi.]

Comment: That won't help you much, but FYI, it is _not_ a general limitation of that version - I am running multiple Windows 10 guests on 5.1.6 under 2560x1440x32, and have no issues. I would check the memory allcation you gave for the video memory - make sure it has enough.

Comment: Same issue here, the resolution wont go higher than 1600x1200.Manualy adding a custom resolution did not help. i tried `VBoxManage setextradata "win7" CustomVideoMode1 2560x1440x32`...

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Devices -> install Guest VM Additions`
After that you will have to reboot and in `View menu choose Full screen`. 
It might helps.